# How to append line after a sed range match

Tags: sed

/etc/named.conf has record like this:

```
zone "domain.com" in{
  type master;
  file "local/domain.com";
};
```

I am trying to append the line:

```
allow-update { key "update"; };
```

after multiline matching:

```
zone "domain.com" in{
   type master;
```

With the desired result:

```
zone "domain.com" in{
  type master;
  allow-update { key "update"; };
  file "local/domain.com";
};
```

The code I have is very close, but it adds the line twice, once after each line in the match so I end up with:

```
zone "domain.com" in{
  allow-update { key "update"; };
  type master;
  allow-update { key "update"; };
  file "local/domain.com";
};
```

This is the sed command I'm using where $insert has the desired line to insert:

```
sed -i "/zone \"${domain}\"/ ,  /^ *type master/a\ ${insert}" "$named_conf_file"
```

Can this be fixed without some involved coding?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/zone "domain.com" in{/{n;/type master;/!ba;p;s/\S.*/allow-update { key "update"; };/}' file
```

Match the line `zone "domain.com" in{`.

Print it and fetch the next line.

If the following line contains `type master;`, print it and substitute the non-whitespace for the value `allow-update { key "update"; };`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '
    /zone "domain.com" in/,/type master/ {
        h
        p
        d
    }
    x
    /./ {
        i \
  allow-update { key "update"; };
        s/.*//
    }
    x
' "$named_conf_file"
```

- if we are on the range of lines that we want to append to:

  - set hold
  - print current line
- otherwise:

  - check if hold is empty

    - if not empty:

      - print the new line
      - clear the hold
  - (implicit) print the current line

Comment: depending on the content of the file, there are various ways this code could fail. eg. if `zone "domain.com" in{` stanza has no `type master` but another stanza does

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v dom='domain.com' -v add='allow-update { key "update"; };' '
    { print }
    ($0 ~ /type master;/) && (p ~ "zone \""dom"\"") {
        sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"")
        print $0 add
    }
    { p=$0 }
' file
zone "domain.com" in{
  type master;
  allow-update { key "update"; };
  file "local/domain.com";
};
```

If you want to modify the input file and have GNU awk (which I assume you do since you're using GNU sed) then change `awk` to `awk -i inplace` at the front or with any awk add `> tmp && mv tmp file` at the back.